# iOS App freezes during Parse Asynchronous Query

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, parse-platform, xcode6

I'm querying Parse for some objects using a background asynchronous call. However, while the query is happening, the app freezes. I can't interact with it. Once the query is done and the objects are loaded though, the app catches up. It's my understanding that the app should be responsive during the query because it's a background asynchronous task.

For example, when the app loads the query begins -> if I press back on the nav bar during the query nothing happens -> the query finishes and my objects appear -> the app pops up to the root controller in response to the earlier touches

The app is not frozen after the query. It responds normally.
I'm not sure if the problem is my placement of the query, that the phone just gets slow when it parses, or what. Any help would be appreciated!!

Relevant code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Loads the users to be rated
    [self loadNewUsersAndAd];
}

-(void)loadNewUsersAndAd{
    self.usersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserObjects"];
    [self.usersQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.queryingForUsers = YES;
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"It looks like we couldn't update your current games! Make sure you're connected to the internet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            self.queryingForUsers = NO;
        }
        else 
        {
            //The query was successful
            self.usersArray = objects;
           [self loadNewImages];
           self.queryingForUsers = NO;

    }

}];



}
```

Comment: What does `loadNewImages` do?  Does it update UI elements?  If it does it should be dispatched on the main queue

Comment: The query loads a userObject from parse, which has three pictures associated with it. Once the userObject is loaded, I update the UI with the associated pictures by calling loadNewImages. Is the problem that I'm including this UI update in the query? And if so, how else could I go about it? Thanks for cluing me in so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't update UI elements from a background thread.  Ensure that your `loadNewImages` is dispatched on the main queue -

```
 self.usersArray = objects;
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self loadNewImages];
     self.queryingForUsers = NO;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! However this doesn't appear to be fixing the issue.

Comment: Then you have a problem in some code that isn't shown here.  You can try single-stepping in your debugger

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a property set for self.usersQuery? Are you using it elsewhere? I don't know why you have a property set for a query because I can't see the rest of your code, but it may be backtracking when you call this query causing the confusion to the app. There usually isn't a need to set a property for a parse query, but you can try the following:

```
-(void)loadNewUsersAndAd{
PFQuery *usersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserObjects"];
[usersQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        //Other Code
    }
    else 
    {
       //Other Code
}
}];
```

Additionally, Paulw11 is correct, you shouldn't be updating your UI elements in the background thread, even if adding the code he showed doesn't work right now, that doesn't mean its not correct. Keep it in your project because it is correct, your issue resides somewhere else.

There are a lot of variables here, how are you displaying the images, are you displaying them all at once, reusing cells etc. Look at your implementation for loading the images, thats more than likely your problem. Comment out that line and troubleshoot from there. If it still lags with the image code commented out you have an additional issue to look for.

Comment: Thank you for your input! It's good to have a confirmation on Paulw's answer, I appreciate it! I'll step through my code. Also I made the query a property because I call [self.usersQuery cancel] in another thread on a contingency. Maybe that's the problem.